# Importing from parallel directories with python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, python-unittest

I have recently started working on a project and have been tasked with implementing some new features as well as unit testing for those features. I have been trying to import modules into the unit testing file but when I run it I come across an ImportError: No module named Developing.algorithms when I try to import into test_algorithms.py

I have tried importing with both

```
from Developing import algorithms as algo
```

and

```
import Developing.algorithms as algo
```

My structure is similar to this Testing project that I made:

```
Testing/
    __init__.py
    Developing/
        __init__.py
        algorithms.py
    Master (Stable)/
    Tests/
        __init__.py
        test_algorithms.py
```

And I run into:

```
ImportError: No module named Developing.algorithms
```

Or when I change the import to: from Developing import algorithms

```
ImportError: No module named Developing
```

I have read many similar questions and from those I have learned to include **init**.py files into each directory that has a file that I want to import. I currently do not have any errors according to PyCharm but when I run it from terminal I run into that import error. I also do not want to modify the system / python path as I read that everyone that uses the project would have to so the same. So how can I import from parallel directories without changing paths?

Comment: Where are you importing this from? Where in your directory structure would that script in which you are importing `Developing.algorithms` lie?

Comment: I am trying to import into test_algorithms.py

Comment: What do your `import` statements look like? Something like `import Developing.algorithms` or `import Testing.Developing.algorithms`? Sometimes you have to write the entire path name.

Comment: I have tried both: "from Developing import algorithms as algo" and "import Developing.algorithms as algo." When I use Testing.Developing.algorthms I run into a "Unresolved reference" in PyCharm despite having the __init__ files

Comment: possible duplicate of [Attempted relative import in non-package even with \_\_init\_\_.py](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to add the directory `Testing` into your `PYTHONPATH` env variable, to be able to import `Developing.algorithms` directly (or the directory above `Testing` to be able to import `Testing.Developing.algorithms` ).

In windows, you can set the PYTHONPATH variable as -

```
set PYTHONPATH=\path\to\Testing\;%PYTHONPATH%
```

In Bash , you can try -

```
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/testing/:$PYTHONPATH
```

Programatically (from python) , you can do the following before you try to import `Developing.algorithms` -

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/Testing/')
from Developing import algorithms # or how ever you want to import.
```

Also, you do not need to do all of the above, any one would do - either setting PYTHONPATH env variable, or using `sys.path` .

Comment: This seems to work, however; won't the path be different for every computer? I will look into using os to over come this.

Comment: The correct solution to setting the path is to always use a virtualenv.

Comment: @user3591079 Would you be testing this on multiple computers? If so, I think you should consider restructuring your directory structure such that it is possible to import the files without setting anything in `PYTHONPATH` . Or you can use `sys.path.append` with relative path to `Testing` folder.

Comment: @AnandSKumar Yes this will be tested on multiple computers, which is why I am hesitant to use the PYTHONPATH method. I will look into sys.path.append using the relative path. I am also a new member on this project so I am hesitant to recommend restructuring the project. In that case, would it be recommended to put the Testing folder within the folder that has files to test? For instance, /Developing/Tests?

Comment: @user3591079 I would say it would be recomend putting the testing script side by side (on the same folder) as the scripts that they would be testing (that is `Developing` , I hope)